# Testing with boost

Tags: c++, testing, boost, boost-test

Can someone write step by step what to do to start using testing facilities from boost? For example I have a class:

```
class A
{
public:
int multiplyByTwo(const int input)
{
return input * 2;
}
};
```

and I would like to set test cases for multiplyByTwo fnc. How? In which files? What steps do I need to perform in order to run it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone already has written this down for you - there is a ['hello world' introduction](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/hello-the-testing-world.html) in the Boost docs.

For your case, I think it should look something like this:

```
#include "A.hpp"
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test )
{
    my_class A( /* whatever you need to construct it right */ );

    BOOST_CHECK( A.multiply_by_two(2) == 4 );
}
```

EDIT:
There is a [slightly more extensive tutorial here](http://www.alittlemadness.com/2009/03/31/c-unit-testing-with-boosttest/) that should help when you start to taxonomize your tests.

Comment: @Steve The missing info: BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test ) - thats the second 'screen' in which file am I suppose to place it? What is my_test?

Comment: @There is nothing we can do - see edit. Let me know if more problems arise.

Comment: Shouldn't custom headers be in " "

Comment: @Steve Great thanks it seems to work now. So basically every new test I'm just placing in BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE?

Comment: @There is nothing we can do - see 2nd edit. That would work, yes.

Comment: @Steve once again thanks, I was driven demented by lack of good tutorials (step by step and I mean step by step) on the web.